# Determining default character set of platform in Java

Tags: java, character-encoding

I am programming in Java

I have the code as:

```
byte[] b = test.getBytes();
```

In the api it is specified that if we do not specify character encoding it takes the default platform character encoding.

What is meant by "default platform character encoding" ?

Does it mean the Java encoding or the OS encoding ?

If it means OS encoding the how can i check the default character encoding of Windows and Linux ? Is there anyway we can get the default character encoding using command line ?

Comment: You should clarify exactly what you mean.  Start with why you want the information.

Comment: If you can't find the questions you previously asked, just click anywhere where your name appears as a link like here: [Anand](http://stackoverflow.com/users/226906/anand) and in the top bar. You can find the questions there, you've pretty much unaccepted questions (note: questions are spread over pages!). Review them once again and vote/accept some.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means the default character encoding of the JVM that you're running on,

To check the default encoding you can do the following:

```
System.getProperty("file.encoding");
```

that will return the default encoding (and the one used by getBytes() above).

Comment: ...but don't bother.  There are very few valid reasons to use `String.getBytes()`, and when you do use it you should always specify an encoding rather than rely on the default.  The same goes for the `new String(byte[])` constructors.

Comment: __This answer is completely incorrect.__ file.encoding returns things like `COMPAT`. Reading it out makes no sense for client code trying to figure out, well, anything.

Answer (score 4):

**The answer to this question has changed with the release of java 18**.

Since Java 18, [the default charset of the JVM is always UTF-8 regardless of the underlying OS's platform default charset (JEP-400)](https://openjdk.org/jeps/400).

This affects almost everything:

- [`Charset.defaultCharset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset()) (always returns the same thing as `StandardCharsets.UTF8` which should use instead if that's what you want.
- The value of `System.getProperty("file.encoding")`. This isn't *actually* any sort of relevant encoding, in that this is a parameter you send *to* the JVM, not something you're meant to read. It's always worked this way - for example, this can get you the value `COMPAT`. Which isn't an encoding, but means: Hey, JVM, instead of UTF-8, use the OS's default encoding. Hence, **do not read this value**.
- The behaviour of every method that converts bytes to characters or vice versa and doesn't accept an explicit `Charset` parameter. Such as `new String(bytes)`, `someStr.getBytes()`, `new FileWriter(filePath)`, and many, *many* more. **However**, all methods in `java.nio.file.Files` that do this use UTF-8 and always have, regardless of `Charset.defaultCharset()`. You *can* mess with it though. For example, by invoking `java -Dfile.encoding=COMPAT` - then these methods all use your platform's native encoding instead.

Your question breaks down to two subtly different questions:

- If I use these `new String(byteArr)` style methods, what encoding does java actually use?
- What is the OS's platform encoding - if I write a text file the user is supposed to e.g. `cat thatfile.txt` later, what encoding should I write it in so that they'll be able to read it, presuming that they don't change their OS's default encoding (if they do that, all bets are off).

If you ask the first question, the correct answer is `Charset.defaultCharSet()`.

If you ask the second question, that's a lot trickier. Because **it depends on the JVM version** - that means it's impossible to test that you do it right unless you set up a complicated testing framework that runs your unit tests on multiple JVM versions.

### Java 18+

This is how:

```
Charset c = System.console().charset();
```

Technically that doesn't return "the OS's native encoding", it returns "the encoding in use by the console". One particular issue is that various platforms do not *have* a console (the above code would result in a `NullPointerException` - the spec of `console()` says it may return `null`). Often IDE's have a little console-ish thing to do keyboard input and output straight from a view inside your IDE, and they often have no console, or broken implementations. Hence, I strongly advise you *do not* use the above code, and instead use:

```
Charset c = Charset.forName(System.getProperty("native.encoding"));
```

Also, `System.console().charset()` causes a `NoSuchMethodError` on JDK16 and below - as it was introduced in 17. Yet another reason to use the `native.encoding` system property.

### Java 8

... unfortunately, the `native.encoding` sysproperty has only been added in JDK18. and Console.charset() in JDK17. Hence, in Java 8, the above would fail because the property's value is `null` (because it doesn't exist) / won't compile / will cause `NoSuchMethodError`. You'd just go with `Charset.defaultCharset()` as they haven't gone through JEP400 yet.

### Java any version

Hence, you get into this utter mess, to get the platform native encoding regardless of JVM release:

```
String nativeEncodingDescriptor = System.getProperty("native.encoding");
Charset nativeEncoding = nativeEncodingDescriptor == null ?
   Charset.defaultCharset() :
   Charset.forName(nativeEncodingDescriptor);
```

You'd think there'd be a utility method for that. It doesn't exist, of course: If the core java libraries were to add it, you.. wouldn't be able to invoke it on JDK8 as it didn't exist back then. Hence, write that utility method yourself. Perhaps take some solace in the fact everybody messes this up.

### About output

The vast majority of needs to determine native encoding is for writing to `System.out`; after all, that's interacting with the system, *and* they are byte-based (both `in` and `out` are).

Fortunately (?) the `PrintWriter` representing `System.out` is actually properly configured; its charset encoding will be the native encoding. You can 'just' call `System.out.println("☃")` in a text file, save it using UTF-8 encoding, invoke `javac` with `-encoding UTF8`, then run the resulting classfile and assuming your console's font supports the unicode snowman, you'll see a snowman. On any JDK version.

This rule is trickier, though, if you pipe text data straight to the byte-based methods of `PrintStream`. You'd have to apply the proper encoding; use the above snippet to determine this.

**`System.in` is a much bigger issue**.

That's a simple `InputStream` and it has no methods to read characters from it at all. Folks who want to read keyboard input tend to toss `System.in` at `Scanner`. This is a mistake (scanner isn't really designed to parse keyboard input; there's a reason every 5th `java` tagged question on SO is about misunderstanding how it works).

**This is broken on JDK18+**. Because scanner will apply the default charset (i.e. `UTF-8`, on JDK18+). Yes, one of the most common java lines: `new Scanner(System.in)`, is broken these days.

Improvements to 'first steps java' are on the way, and one of these improvements is hopefully to ditch scanner and write a much better 'interact with the console' concept. Latest indications on the relevant OpenJDK mailing lists seem to indicate this is probably going to happen.

Once those APIs are out, use them. Until then, this is really the only way to write a really simple java console app:

```
public class ExampleApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Scanner keyboard = getKeyboard();
  }

  static Scanner getKeyboard() {
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in. getNativeCharset());
    s.useDelimiter("\\R"); // Fix the nextLine v nextX nuttiness.
  }

  static Charset getNativeCharset() {
    String nativeEncodingDescriptor = System.getProperty("native.encoding");
    return nativeEncodingDescriptor == null ?
      Charset.defaultCharset() :
      Charset.forName(nativeEncodingDescriptor);
}
```

Also, every method in the core libraries outside of the `java.nio.file` package that converts bytes to chars or vice versa that defaults its charset (such as `new String(bytes)` or the *entirety* of `FileWriter`) **is broken** and unsalvageably so: If your IDE or linter tool supports a denylist of methods/constructors that must never ever be used, all of these methods should be on the list.

Every time you write code that converts bytes to chars or vice versa, you should call the variant that lets you explicitly define charset. And then write code so that no confusion can exist; use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`, or, if you intend to want native encoding, use the `.getNativeEncoding()` utility method you put in your project, pasted from the snippet above.

`java.nio.file` is the exception - you can call the charset-less variants if UTF-8 is what you want. I can see an argument for also calling the charset-ful versions just to avoid confusion. After all, the version that is charset-less behaves differently on JDK17- vs JDK18+ and is thus broken.

If your command line java app doesn't look like that, or it calls any of those methods, it's subtly broken.