# Why (char)194 == 'Â' instead of (char)182 == 'Â'

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I tried  bitwise shifting operator (<<1) on `char 'a'` and got output `'Â'` according to the compiler but if I see the binary for `'a' 1100001 = 97` and after shifting it's `11000010 = 194`, the ASCII code for `'Â' is 182` and ASCII code 194 belongs to a box drawing character. I don't understand why the compiler shows 'Â' for ASCII code 194?

Link for ASCII code reference: [Box drawing character single line horizontal down](http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/extended-ascii-code/box-drawings-single-line-horizontal-down-character-ascii-code-194.html)

Comment: There are only 128 characters in ASCII.

Comment: I question your source. [This site](http://www.rapidtables.com/code/text/ascii-table.htm) shows that Â is extended ASCII 194.

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen There are another 128 in extended ASCII, to make use of that last bit in each byte.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy Extended ASCII is not standardized. It just means ASCII plus 128 other characters.

Comment: "According to the compiler" - what does the compiler have to do with it? I assume that this is the result of *running* the program, not compiling it. Then you need to tell - what is your platform default encoding? (see : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677419/determining-default-character-set-of-platform-in-java) - what you print out is printed with that encoding, unless you explicitly specify your encoding. To be sure, show your code. See [mcve]

Comment: The whole bit shift detail is a red herring. You could have just asked why `(char)194 == 'Â'`.

Answer (score 3):

**[ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Character_set)** is a standard and only has 128 codes.

[Extended ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_ASCII) is not a single standard, and uses the remaining 128 codes available in a byte. As Wikipedia says it:

> There are many extended ASCII encodings (more than **220** DOS and Windows **codepages**).

From that we can conclude that there are 220 different standards for Extended ASCII. You are only looking at one of them, and not the one that has anything to do with Java.

In fact, the link you referenced is using [code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850#Character_set), where character 194 (hex C2) is `┬`, and `Â` is at 182 (hex B6).

---

Java uses **[Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)**, where a `char` value is actually a [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) encoded Unicode character. There are currently **136,755** codes, as of Unicode 10.0 (June 2017).

The first 128 codes ([Basic Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Latin_(Unicode_block)#Compact_table)) are the same as ASCII. The next 128 codes ([Latin-1 Supplement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin-1_Supplement_(Unicode_block)#Compact_table)) are the same as Extended ASCII codepage [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1).

In Unicode, character 194 (hex C2) is `Â`, also known as ['LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A WITH CIRCUMFLEX' (U+00C2)](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00c2/index.htm).

Answer (score 2):

The link you supplied is the wrong Extended ASCII for Java, see here:

http://www.idevelopment.info/data/Programming/programming_resources/PROGRAMMING_ascii_table.shtml

In this table, 194 = `Â` as expected.

Comment: The OP's link is "more correct" since it explains that they mean "Codepage 437" when they say "Extended ASCII". There are very many extended ASCII's - and your link doesn't seem to specify which they mean with it (examples: codepage 437, any windows codepage, ISO-8859-1, UTF-8, etc.)

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I saw that too in the linked article, and found it very funny, because it is not code page [437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437#Character_set), but code page [**850**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850#Character_set), e.g. character 182 (hex B6) is `Â` in code page 850, but `╢` in code page 437.