# What encoding/character set does Java use per default for BufferedReader?

Tags: java, encoding, bufferedreader

What encoding/character set does Java use per default when we create a new `BufferedReader` object without providing an encoding explicitly?

For example:

```
try (final BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("my_file.txt"))) {
  reader.readLine(); // What encoding is used to read the file?
}
```

Comment: If you want to know _how_ the default is set, dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006276/what-is-the-default-encoding-of-the-jvm https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749064/how-to-find-the-default-charset-encoding-in-java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677419/determining-default-character-set-of-platform-in-java and more

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`BufferedReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html) doesn't do any decoding.  It is a wrapper for another `Reader` ... which may or may not do decoding.

[`FileReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html) decodes using the JVM's default character encoding, as returned by [`Charset.defaultCharset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset())

The javadoc states:

> Convenience class for reading character files. *The constructors of this class assume that the default character encoding and the default byte-buffer size are appropriate.* To specify these values yourself, construct an `InputStreamReader` on a `FileInputStream`.

Answer (score 4):

`FileReader` is an `InputStreamReader` which uses `FileInputStream` as input, and an [`InputStreamReader`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.InputStream)) uses the default charset when constructed without specified charset.

In the source code jdk10, it use  [`Charset.defaultCharset()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#defaultCharset()):

```
public static StreamDecoder forInputStreamReader(InputStream in,
                                                 Object lock,
                                                 String charsetName)
    throws UnsupportedEncodingException
{
    String csn = charsetName;
    if (csn == null)
        csn = Charset.defaultCharset().name(); // get default charset
    try {
        if (Charset.isSupported(csn))
            return new StreamDecoder(in, lock, Charset.forName(csn));
    } catch (IllegalCharsetNameException x) { }
    throw new UnsupportedEncodingException (csn);
}
```

which

> Returns the default charset of this Java virtual machine.
>
> The default charset is determined during virtual-machine startup and
>   typically depends upon the locale and charset of the underlying
>   operating system.

You can print it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());
}
```

Comment: You should include an actual JavaDoc reference which connects this to `FileReader`; I could not find one.